# How to Control Deployments in TFS

Tags: tfs, branch

I have 3 solutions in Team Foundation Server.  Prod which is branched to QAS which is branched to DEV.

I do all of my work in the DEV branch and check in any changes to this branch and when I check this in I associate the ChangeSet with a Work Item in TFS.  Let's say I have 4 ChangeSets (ChangeSet #101, 102, 103, 104) at this point each one is associated with a different bug (Bug #1, 2, 3, and 4).

I then deploy the DEV branch of the project out for internal testing.  Once this has been verified I then merge the DEV branch into the QAS and then check all of these changes in as ChangeSet #104.

Now here is where I have a problem.  After the external testing Bug 1 and 2 have been confirmed and are ready to get deployed to Prod, but bug 3 and 4 are not.  If I go into the Prod branch and merge from QAS back into prod it will grab all of the changes from QAS and push them into the prod branch.  But this is not what I want because it will give me the code that is in error for bugs 3 and 4.  What I really want is to just grab the same changes that came from ChangeSet 101 and 102, but I can't say to just pull in those changes because those were from DEV to QAS, which all then became a single ChangeSet.

So my question is how to get the Environment/ChangeSet setup in a manner, so that I could bring over just the pieces that I want.

Answer (score 1):

You really can't do this without invalidating QA's work. Generally, releases are all-or-nothing. Every time you change code, you invalidate all prior testing done. This can be mitigated by having unit and integration tests to provide some safeguards against regressions, but fundamentally any time the code changes, something unexpected can break. It's worse in poorly architected spaghetti systems, but it's a risk in even the best-designed system.

Let's say you release once a week. You fix 4 bugs in that timeframe and pass all of them off to QA.

QA is able to validate that 2 of the bugs are fixed. What happens if you remove the other 2 bugfixes that aren't validated?

1. Nothing. The bugs and the code changed is actually completely orthogonal. Whew.
2. The combination of Bugfix 1 and Bugfix 3 actually fixes Bug Omega, that you didn't even know existed. Removing Bugfix 3 *introduces a different bug*. QA won't catch it because as far as they're concerned they tested and everything was working.

If QA typically can't complete their testing for a release within the timespan allocated for the release, then you have a bottleneck somewhere that needs to be identified and removed.